# Scrapy xpath syntax error when selecting more classes

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I would like to select all divs with classes consist of `cl-list-header-title`, `sc-grid-col-s-12`, `sc-grid-col-l-7` and `sc-grid-col-xl-7`. When I try to do it like in scrapy selectors examples, I receive SyntaxError: invalid syntax and I have no idea why. I think I do not missing any parenthesis or quotation mark. Could anybody explain where is the problem?

```
In [30]: response.xpath('//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' cl-list-header-titlesc-grid-col-s-12sc-grid-col-l-7sc-grid-col-xl-7 ' )]')
  File "<ipython-input-30-c35a162c1f9e>", line 1
    response.xpath('//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' cl-list-header-titlesc-grid-col-s-12sc-grid-col-l-7sc-grid-col-xl-7 ' )]')
                                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to inconsistent quotes usage. Try to replace

```
response.xpath('//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' cl-list-header-titlesc-grid-col-s-12sc-grid-col-l-7sc-grid-col-xl-7 ' )]')
```

with

```
response.xpath("//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' cl-list-header-titlesc-grid-col-s-12sc-grid-col-l-7sc-grid-col-xl-7 ' )]")
```